# How to change select box value using JCF plugin?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a select box that uses jcf plugin. As documenation says we have to refresh method to change the value but it is not changing. Below here is what i have tried?

```js
$(function() {
    jcf.replaceAll();
});

function changeValue() {
  $("#mgloc_npgpo").val('1')
  jcf.getInstance($("#mgloc_npgpo")).refresh()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jcf/1.2.3/js/jcf.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jcf/1.2.3/js/jcf.select.js"></script>

     <div class="select-holder"><label>Selection</label>
        <div class="select-wrap"><input type="hidden" id="mgloc_340b" value=""/> 
            <div class="select-wrap"><input type="hidden" id="mgloc_340b" value=""/> 
        <select id="mgloc_npgpo" multiple="multiple" 
            data-jcf="{&quot;wrapNative&quot;: false, &quot;wrapNativeOnMobile&quot;: false, &quot;useCustomScroll&quot;: false, &quot;multipleCompactStyle&quot;: true}" class="jcf-hidden">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Non-Primary</option>
<option value="1">value 1</option>
<option value="2">value 2</option>
        </select>
    <div class="errorMsg hide">&#160;</div>
    </div>
        <div class="errorMsg hide">&#160;</div>
        </div>
        <button style="margin-top: 100px;" onClick="changeValue()">change value</button>
       
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo

Your id name `mgloc_npgpo` not `mgloc_ngpo`

In your js code you have used `mgloc_ngpo`at every place. which should be `mgloc_npgpo`

```js
$(function() {
    jcf.replaceAll();
});

function changeValue() {
  $("#mgloc_npgpo").val('1')
  jcf.getInstance($("#mgloc_npgpo")).refresh()
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jcf/1.2.3/js/jcf.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jcf/1.2.3/js/jcf.select.js"></script>

 <div class="select-holder"><label>Selection</label>
    <div class="select-wrap"><input type="hidden" id="mgloc_340b" value=""/> 
        <select jcf id="mgloc_npgpo" 
            data-jcf="{&quot;wrapNative&quot;: false, &quot;wrapNativeOnMobile&quot;: false, &quot;useCustomScroll&quot;: false, &quot;multipleCompactStyle&quot;: true}" class="jcf-hidden">
            <option value="" selected="selected">Select Non-Primary</option>
            <option value="1" >value1</option>
            <option value="2" >value2</option>
        </select>
    <div class="errorMsg hide">&#160;</div>
    </div>
    <button onClick="changeValue()">change value</button>
   
    </div>
```